# what does this phrase mean?

Tags: functions

Can someone explain in everyday language what "*monotonically*" and "*quadrilaterally*" mean in the following sentence?

> Muscular torques increase *monotonically* with increasing diameter for lids with rough grip surfaces and *quadrilaterally* for smooth grips.

Comment: I can understand "quadratically", but I have never heard the expression "quadrilaterally"

Comment: Thank you Gary. That does help to clarify the meaning a little.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Quadrilaterally" is probably what a confused person wrote when they meant "quadratically".  And "monotonically" in the usage of mathematicians would simply mean that one of the quanitities, muscular torque, always increases as the other one, diameter, increases, as opposed to sometimes increasing and sometimes decreasing depending on the diamater.  But in this case I suspect it's another confused usage and maybe "linearly" was meant.